# After successful installation, Is it possible create a database without DBCA?

Tags: oracle, oracle-11g

Apologies, for I am not familiar with the Oracle Database environment. Please help me to learn. :)

As the title states, can someone please provide the steps required to create a database manually through SQL, without using DBCA? Any links or posts are welcome.

Thanks.

Comment: Can you take a step back and explain what problem you're trying to solve?  First, if you're not familiar with Oracle, are you sure that you're using the term "database" in the Oracle sense?  An Oracle database is more similar to, say, a SQL Server instance while a SQL Server database is more similar to an Oracle schema.  Second, if you're not familiar with Oracle, why wouldn't you use the DBCA?  You certainly can execute a `create database` statement but you're generally better off particularly as an inexperienced user going through the GUI.

Comment: Yes. Right . DBCA is convenient to create a database . But I think using the SQL or commands to create the database can know more about something been done behind the DBCA. Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes. First you need a parameter file (init.ora). The only mandatory parameter is db_name to have a fully working database.

Steps

1 - Create the parameter file:

```
[myhostname@oracle $] vi $ORACLE_HOME/dbs/initorcl.ora

db_name='orcl'

:wq
```

2 - Export ORACLE_SID to reflect the db_name you which to create:

```
[myhostname@oracle $] export ORACLE_SID=orcl
```

3 - Login to sqlplus:

```
[myhostname@oracle $] sqlplus / as sysdba
```

4 - Issue the "startup nomount" command, pointing to the parameter file you have created.

```
SQL> startup nomount pfile = '/u01/app/oracle/product/<version>/dbs/initorcl.ora'
```

5 - Issue the create database command

```
SQL> create database;
```

6 - Run the post database creation scripts:

```
SQL> @?/rdbms/admin/catalog.sql -- Create dictionary views

SQL> @?/rdbms/admin/catproc.sql

SQL> @?/sqlplus/admin/pupbld.sql
```

@ means "run an external script in sqlplus"
? is a wildcard character that represents the ORACLE_HOME path, so if you correctly installed the software and set the environment variables, it must work, otherwise provide the full ORACLE_HOME path.

You may also want to know the "whys" of each stage of the database creation process...

At step 1, you don't have a database (datafiles, controlfiles...), so in order to create a database, you first must have an instance, which is a set of memory structures and background processes, and for that purpose, the only need is a parameter file to startup the instance in nomount. To proceed to the mount stage, you need either a controlfile if the database already exists, or issue the create database command to let Oracle take care of creating the necessary files, tablespaces etc. After that, the database can be mounted and opened, but still the data dictionary views aren't populated. So you just need to run the post scripts to do the job.

[Reference](https://docs.oracle.com/cd/B28359_01/server.111/b28310/create003.htm)

Answer (score 1):

Yes, databases can be created without using DBCA from command line.

1) you need to export required environment variables

2) Create a parameter file (init$sid.ora) under $ORACLE_HOME/dbs
substitute $sid with your instance name.

3) Create a SQL script for database creation

4) Connect to sqlplus, put the instance in no mount state and run the script to create database and perform post creation steps.

This is the manual way to create a database.

Answer (score 1):

If you want to create database without dbca, there is simple way to generate a shell script that is foolproof and you can modify your required information e.g datafiles location, sid names and all. Try use dbca to generate script, it will be plan shell and sql script. It will not be having code used by dbca. you can edit this script and run on your oracle home.

Comment: Thanks. Is there any tutorial about how to generate shell script with DBCA?

Comment: Yes, here is silent command that generates shell script which you can modify based on your needs.  https://docs.oracle.com/database/121/ADMIN/create.htm#ADMIN14042

Comment: dbca -generateScripts 
   -templateName template_name
   -gdbName global_database_name
   [-scriptDest script_destination]